# Issue on NotificatioApi C#

Tags: c#, telegram

I have written a line of code in C# which sends a message to a telegram account, as the documentation says I have written the code as below:

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            var api = NotificatioApi.Initialize("My api hash here");
            api.SendMessage("My phone Number", "تست از سی شارپ");
}
```

when I click on the btnSend it sends the message successfully but sent message doesn't shown in the telegram. what is the matter with this line of code?

Comment: Refer to telegegram API documentation for api.SendMessage return types

Comment: Did you: 1) register a hash at Notificatio and used it in the `Initialize` method. 2) use a phone number with only digits (no "+" or anything), and 3) try to send an ASCII string, just to check if they handle international characters ok ?

Comment: seems no problem there check out this one work for me : http://www.dotnettips.info/post/2094/%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%84-%D9%BE%DB%8C%D8%A7%D9%85-%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%AA%D8%A8%D9%84%DB%8C%D8%BA%D8%A7%D8%AA%DB%8C-%D8%A8%D9%87-telegram-%D8%A8%D8%A7-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%B2-c

Comment: @Jcl Thank you for your explanation. I have checked your hints. nothing happened :(

Comment: @persianDeveloper No buddy it's type is void.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If not, pls provide your api_hash to support@notificatio.me

Comment: No Buddy :) Thank you. I will send it now. :) @SochiX